# How to change the text color in a view in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a view where I am trying to change the color of the text but I am unable to do so. Inside the disclaimer view I have tried to add the style as a prop and tried to change the color properties but it won't work. I've done the following:

```
 <View
          style={styles.webview}
          text={
            disclaimerText?.replace('\n', '<br />'), 
            style= {{color: palette.foreground.main}}}
          onScroll={handleScroll}
        />
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use color you have to use the `Text` component like this.

```
<View style={styles.webview} onScroll={handleScroll}>
    <Text text={
            disclaimerText?.replace('\n', '<br />'), 
            style= {{color: palette.foreground.main}}} >Some text</Text>
</View>
```